# mod_rewrite rule using date regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rule that when user types in this url:

```
domain.com/09/13/2013/thisIsMyPageTitle
```

That url stays in browser window, but content from this url is displayed:

```
domain.com/contentlibrary/thisIsMyPageTitle
```

This is my rule that I currently get an error with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d[/])$(.*) /contentlibrary/$1  [L]
```

I'm trying to match the date with regular expression, and use the (.*) from the initial url in the second one that holds the content and actually exists.

Comment: _I currently get an error with_  -  Well don't make us beg... what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, it was an internal server error that displayed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not going to do anything with date then why bother being precise with date semantics. **You can simplify your regex:**

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/([^/]+)/?$ /contentlibrary/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Great way to move a Wordpress blog that used dates in the URL to one that no longer does.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're getting is probably because you have unescaped spaces in your regex. Specifically these:

```
[- /.]
```

The spaces get interpreted by mod_rewrite as the delimiter between parameters. Additionally, you have this:

```
$(.*)
```

at the end of your pattern. The `$` matches the *end of the string*, so you want those swapped:

```
(.*)$
```

So:

```
^((0[1-9]|1[012])[-\ /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\ /.](19|20)\d\d[/])(.*)$
```

shold be the pattern that you want.

Comment: This answers my question the most complete so far... However one more point in the original question was that I desire the url with the date to remain in the browser window, and simply load the content from the url /contentLibrary   Is mod_rewrite the correct tool to do this? I am most certain I have done this before similarly.